# Activity#setTitle works, but Activity#getWindow()#setTitle does not

Tags: android

While in Activity, I can change the title using:

```
setTitle("new title");
```

This way works. However, I can also get window - using getWindow - and call its getTitle method:

```
getWindow().setTitle("new title");
```

This way does not work. Why?

Comment: if you use `this.getWindow().setTitle("new title");` then second option also work

Comment: So don't use the non-working version :) `Activity#setTitle` also sets the window title. If you do it directly via the window the activity will not know the title which I guess leads to that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with level 10. To solve it, check if your **Activity** extends **ActionBarActivity**.

If it does, instead using:

```
setTitle("title");
```

use:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("title");
```

It worked for me. :D